# Cannot persist entity list with size greater than some number with UTF-8 encoding in Play 2 Ebean

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am trying to persist an entity in UTF-8 Encoding.  I am using the following config

```
db.default.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
db.default.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user = ****
db.default.password = ****
db.default.jndiName = DefaultDS
```

my persistence xml is like

```
<persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Ebean.save(entityList) gives

```
c.j.b.ConnectionHandle - Database access problem. Killing off this connection and all remaining connections in the connection pool. SQL State = HY000
a.a.OneForOneStrategy - java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed!
javax.persistence.RollbackException: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed!
```

when entityList.size() is greater than some certain number, for example 15.

However when I remove **?characterEncoding=UTF-8** part from the db url everything works file but I cannot save Chinese strings in proper encoding.

I can save Chinese chars manually

Comment: Can you save these characters in DB manually?

Comment: Yes, I can save Chinese chars manually

Answer (score 0):

If the database is configured to store data in UTF-8 encoding then you don't have to configure Hibernate at all.

A Java String doesn't require an encoding. It's a byte[] that needs the encoding information in order to explain how the bytes should be read.

Whenever reading files/sockets you need to know the encoding because data comes byte after byte so you have to provide the decoding hint.

Make sure your create tables contain the encoding:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    ID             INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,       
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8
```